# Displaying Only The Excerpt In Post

Tags: wordpress

I used the following to place a call for the Excerpt to show, however its showing the full post:-

This is in my function:-

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_excerpts_to_pages' );
function my_add_excerpts_to_pages() {
 add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
```

Also this is my query

```
<?php
// retrieve one post with an ID of 5
query_posts( 'p=1' );

// set $more to 0 in order to only get the first part of the post
global $more;
$more = 0;

// the Loop
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
the_content( 'Read the full post »' );
endwhile;
?>
```

Please can you advise? Thanks

Comment: Why not use `the_excerpt()`?

Comment: Hi @Pekka웃 when i used the the_excerpt it did a fit with my page :S

Comment: That's the right (and only) function to use when you want to show an excerpt, though. Have you tried `the_excerpt()` in the place of `the_content()`? What happens?

Comment: Hi Kirsty, Couldn't you just use the `more` button in the wordpress editor?